# Add space in self closing tags before in self closing tags

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, eslint

How do you include a space before the closing tags in self closing tags with WebStorm/IntelliJ-based products?

Default settings turns `<ReactComp />` to `<ReactComp/>`, which is against one of the rules ([jsx-space-before-closing](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-space-before-closing.md)) in the commonly used AirBNBs Javascript style guide.

Answer (score 231):

Maybe a little confusingly, the setting is under "HTML" code style and not the JS code style in IntelliJ.

Enable the setting "In empty tag" in Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> HTML.

When you do an explicit reformat the space will be added. To ensure that the space is added when autocompleting React components, check the same box in in the Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> **XML** -> Other tab.

Screenshot from 2016-10-12, IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. It works like charme ;-D

Comment: Wow, this caused countless hours of debugging, thank you!

Comment: This works for me when doing an explicit reformat, but not when autocompleting jsx tags. I.e. when the autocomplete box shows while typing and I press enter it still shows the jsx tag without the space before the /

Comment: @Ruben Add the same in XML

Comment: I missed this option. I thought this checkbox belongs to the wrapping settings section. I missed the Spaces headline.

Comment: Is there any option like this for .editorconfig so I can propagate this to team?

Comment: Perfect! This works for Webstorm as well.

Comment: @ViktorSulak, a bit late, but added the .editorconfig answer.

Answer (score 8):

The .editorconfig way.

```
[**]
ij_html_space_inside_empty_tag = true
```

Here's how you find the name of any option. The same IDEA Code Style page has a gear button with an option to export to .editorconfig:
[image]
But this exports all the options, it's a 1070 line file in my case. So you export once to cfg1, change the desired setting through UI, export again to cfg2, and then compare the two configs to find the one option that changed.

Answer (score 0):

For Rider and C# project add this line to [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file:

```
[*.csproj]
ij_xml_space_inside_empty_tag = true
```